# How to change Kubernetes nodes cidr?

Tags: kubernetes, cidr

The cluster has CIDR 10.100.32.0/22, but master and worker nodes have 172.168.0.0/24

I tried changing each node's CIDR with `kubectl edit node node_name`, but vim only saves a temporary YAML file.

Which I also tried to apply, but didn't seem to work.

I also tried to use kubectl patch command, but that didn't seem to work too, returning:

> The Node "node_name" is invalid: spec.podCIDRs: Forbidden: node
> updates may not change podCIDR except from "" to valid

When I check **kube-controller-manager** logs (which has CrashLoopBackOff status), they show:

> Error starting "nodeipam" error starting controllers: failed to mark
> cidr[172.168.10.0/24] at idx [0] as occupied for node: node_name: cidr
> 172.168.10.0/24 is out the range of cluster cidr 10.100.32.0/22

Any advice would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: I met the same problem,have you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully changed the CIDR by reinitialising the whole Kubernetes cluster.

Passing the CIDR as a parameter with `kubeadm init`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that field is read-only for security purposes. You would have to reinitialize the node from scratch. In general changing node IPs on the fly gets very dicey, I would just make a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the `Node` resources, and removed any properties that is being book-kept by Kubernetes, like `managedFields`. Changed the `podCIDR` to my liking, then remove the previous `Node` resource and then applied the new one. Then restarted Kubelets everywhere. It did the trick.